# What does the "image" tag mean in the docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble understanding exactly the usage of the "image" option in the following docker-compose file.

1. In the `api` service, the image tag looks like its being used to *name* the built api image as `server`
2. However in the `redis` service, the image tag looks like its telling docker which image to pull from dockerhub.
3. Finally, what image is the `worker` service pulling? There is no build tag to refer to a dockerfile nor is there an image being pulled. There is no `app` image defined as well so really confused how this is even working?

```
version: '3'


services:
  api:
    build: ./server
    image: server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/server
    command: "python -m server.app"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"
    command: ["sh", "-c", "redis-server --appendonly yes"]
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api 
  worker:
    image: app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: "python -m server.worker"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the documentation for [`image`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image) explains this well.

The difference is primarily whether the images exists or not. If it doesn't exist, the image tag will be used by the `build` to create an image and name it using the `image` tag value.

To answer your questions directly:

1. The `api` service will build an image called `server` if one doesn't exist
2. The `redis` service will run an image `redis:latest. If it exists locally (pulled), that image will be used. If not, it will default to dockerhub and pull it.
3. The `worker` service uses an image called `app`.

Comment: Got it for the first 2 points. Still confused about #3 though. There is no app image on the repository nor is there an app image locally. So where is the worker service building an image from?

Comment: It is not building any image.If there is no image, it is supposed to fail. Does the `worker` service run?

Comment: @franklinsijo Yes, worker service runs just fine! That's what is most surprising to me.

Comment: If you see `worker` running when you e.g. `docker-compose ps` then you must have an image called `app` locally. `docker image ls | grep "app"`

Comment: Thank you! Yes you are right, I had an old image named app locally. Thanks both of for your help.

Comment: BTW be careful using ":latest". It does not do what most people think it does. You're better placed using a specific version tag. You're best placed using a specific image digest (hash).

Comment: Hi Daz. I wonder if I could trouble you to refrain from adding "hope this helps" to your questions. All answer authors hopes their material helps, so it is rather redundant, and we're ideally looking for technical writing here. This will tend to be removed by volunteer editors, and unfortunately we do not have enough editors to improve the vast amount of material that comes into the platform. So if you can have mercy on editors, and aim for a greater level of succinctness, those volunteers shall be most grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Just like you have observed, `image` option has two different definitions based on how it is specified in the compose file.

1) If `image` option is specified and `build` is not, then compose attempts to pull the image either from local or from the repository.

2) If both `image` and `build` options are specified, then compose tags the built image with this name.

If there is no tag present, `latest` is assumed as the tag. In your `worker` service, unless `app:latest` image is available either in local or remote repository, it is going throw error.

More on the `image` option [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image).